# Vertex (smallest possible value) of $ax^2+bx+c$

Tags: quadratics

The original problem was this: Find the smallest possible value of $ax^2+bx+c$, where a, b, and c are given numbers and $a>0$, and x is some number.

I already asked this, and got a decent answer, but let me get this clear; am I correct here?

The smallest possible value of $ax^2+bx+c=a(-b/2a)+b(-b/2a)+c$. You get it by plugging $-b/2a$ into the place of $x$.
Would you call it a decent answer? Any suggestions to improve it?

Comment: You might want to simplify that.

Answer (score 0):

If you know why you have replaced x  by -b/2a  to get the minimum value then surely that is a decent answer.